# How to access Xampp home page with port changed

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I could not get Xampp to work with the default port, so I changed the port to 8080. Now, I cannot figure out how to load the Xampp home page.

[image]

I tried typing in: `http://localhost:8080/xampp/` and get the following:

[image]

If I try typing the following into the browser, I get a 404 error. `http://localhost:8080/xampp/index.php`

[image]

What do I have to do to be able to get to the Xampp homepage? I want to run phpmyadmin.

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin`

Comment: @wayneOS This did it. Thanks!

Comment: @wayneOS How would I set the credentials for the database password?

Comment: in your Xampp-control panel ther ist right besides Mysql a config-button. Choose `my.ini`. Uncomment and edit the password.

Comment: @wayneOS Thanks! Feel free to leave an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the offer, i did! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the xampp index.php is always at the server root `http://localhost/`. If you changed the port this still applies like `http://localhost:8080/`.

To change the password for your mysql-database open your `my.ini` from the config-button in xampp-control and uncomment and change the line

`#password = your_password`